# How to use subdomain in laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to detect subdomains in routes.php in my L4 website and want to store that subdomain value somewhere so that I can access that value in each controller.

How can I do that ?
Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put this type of method in routes. However, I think it's a better fit for a filter in the 'app/filters.php' file. Try this:

```
Route::filter('getSubdomain', function($route, $request) 
{
    $host = $request->getHost();
    $parts = explode('.', $host);
    $subdomain = $parts[0];

    // Store subdomain in session
    Session::put('subdomain', $subdomain);

});
```

Then add the filter to the route (probably a group route) as follows:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'getSubdomain'), function()
{
 ... add route stuff here ..
});
```

You can read more about how to use Laravel filters here:

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Answer (score 11):

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function() {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes it is a method so that you can access subdomains as a perameter in any controller but I want to detect subdomain in routes.php and want to store it in a session or something else mechanism so I can access that anywhere.

Comment: Do it in `app/start/global.php` then. Store it however you like.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Request to get your domain anywhere.

So, create a BaseController and add a method to get the current domain on all your extended controllers:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function getDomain()
    {
        return Request::getHost();
    }

}
```

And use it:

```
class PostsController extends BaseController {

    public function store()
    {
        $post = new Post;

        $post->domain_id = Domain::where('name', $this->getDomain())->first()->id;

        $post->save();
    }

}
```

Of course, this controller example supposes that you have a Domain model:

```
class Domain extends Eloquent {

    private $table = 'domains';

}
```

**EDIT:**

Unless you have a very good reason for it, you don't have to use routes or store your subdomain on a session, unless you have a **really** good reason for this, it's a smell. Take a look at Laravel's code, there only one session stored by it: Laravel's session.

You can create a helper function:

Create a app/helpers/functions.php file (this is just an example) and add this helper function there:

```
function getCurrentSubdomain()
{
    $domain = Config::get('app.domain');

    preg_match("/^(.*)(\.$domain)$/", Request::getHost(), $parts);

    return $parts[1];
}
```

Open your app/config/app.php and add a domain configuration to it:

```
return array(

    'domain' => 'myapp.com',

        ...
);
```

Add the file to the autoload section of your composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "files": [
         "app/helpers/functions.php"
    ]

},
```

Then you can use it everywhere: controllers, classes, routers, etc. Here's the same example as before, using it:

```
class PostsController extends BaseController {

    public function store()
    {
        $post = new Post;

        $post->domain_id = Domain::where('name', getCurrentSubdomain())->first()->id;

        $post->save();
    }

}
```

You can also create a class and a Facade for it, so you can call this class from anywhere, like Laravel does:

```
Helper::getCurrentSubdomain();
```

Or you can do the same by just creating a class and create a static function (less testable).

Comment: This method will not work for me because  I want to detect subdomain in routes.php and want to store it in a session or something else mechanism so I can access that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is working on my Laravel 4.2 right now.

On your routes file:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.myapp.com'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function($subdomain)
    {
        return "Your subdomain is: ".$subdomain;
    });
});
```

Get subdomain in your controllers or anywhere:

```
$subdomain = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('subdomain');
```